# Ingress traefik to nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I have some problems to "translate" ingress traefik annotiations to ingress nginx

In traefik I have:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingressroutes-backend
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: traefik-pathregex-rm-first-two-args@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{.Values.ingress.host}}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: service-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

for nginx I translated them to:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ingressroutes-backend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{.Values.ingress.host}}
        http:
            paths:
            - pathType: Prefix
                path: "/api"
                backend:
                    service:
                        name: service-svc
                        port:
                            number: 80
```

Maybe someone is here who can tell me if this is ok I worked out.

Answer (score 1):

If it is still interesting:

This is a working example:
You have an app at your root domain `/`
and an backend API at your `/api`-path.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: yourapp-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: demo.your-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-app
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: backend-api
                port:
                  number: 80
```